# tf.data.dataset next(iter()) yields the same value

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to build a datapipeline for inference on some video files. The videos are alot in number hence, I am using the the tf.data.dataset pipeline with a from_generator method to create manageable batches. But the dataset keeps yielding same output over again.

Here is my code:

```
enteclass FrameGenerator:
def __init__(self, video_paths, n_frames, training=False):
    """
        Returns a set of frames from a video in the video_paths list

        Args:
        video_paths: a list of path to videos
        n_frames: Number of frames
        training: A boolean to determine if a training dataset should be created
    """

    self.video_paths = video_paths
    self.n_frames = n_frames
    self.training = training

def __call__(self):
    """
        gets called and yields a set of frames
        each time the instance of the class is called
    """
    video_paths = self.video_paths
    # print(type(video_paths))
    if self.training:
        random.shuffle(video_paths)

    for path in video_paths:
        video_frames = frames_from_video_file(path, self.n_frames)
        file_name = path.split('/')[-1]
        # print(file_name, "filfile")
        yield video_frames, file_namer code here
```

and the code is instantiated here:

```
output_signature = (tf.TensorSpec(shape = (None, None, None, 3), dtype=tf.float32), tf.TensorSpec(shape = None, dtype=tf.string))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(FrameGenerator(video_paths, 20, training=False), output_signature=output_signature)
```

I have the batch size as 10
and an instance of the dataset thus:

```
inference_datasets = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

But when I call this:

```
sample_inference_dataset = next(iter(inference_datasets))
```

and this:

```
enter codesample_inference_dataset[1]
```

It yields the same sets of files.

Comment: I think you'd have a random value when doing that if you set `training=True`

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I see is how you use iter and next together. You're creating a new instance of your iterator then use next() to get the first element, thus you will always get the first element. You'd need to store the iterator on a variable, then use next() on a different line to return the next item on the iterator